# Oracle : String Concatenation is too long

Tags: sql, string, oracle, concatenation

I have below SQL as a part of a view. In one of the schema I am getting "**String Concatenation is too long**" error and not able to execute the view.

Hence I tried the **TO_CLOB()** and now VIEW is not throwing ERROR, but it not returning the result as well it keep on running..

### Please suggest....

**Sql:**

```
SELECT Iav.Item_Id Attr_Item_Id,
LISTAGG(La.Attribute_Name
    ||'|~|'
    || Lav.Attribute_Value
    ||' '
    || Lau.Attribute_Uom, '}~}') WITHIN GROUP (
  ORDER BY ICA.DISP_SEQ,LA.ATTRIBUTE_NAME) AS ATTR
    FROM Item_Attribute_Values Iav,
      Loc_Attribute_Values Lav,
      Loc_Attribute_Uoms Lau,
      Loc_Attributes La,
      (SELECT *
      FROM Item_Classification Ic,
        CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTES CA
      WHERE IC.DEFAULT_CATEGORY='Y'
      AND IC.TAXONOMY_TREE_ID  =CA.TAXONOMY_TREE_ID
      ) ICA
    WHERE IAV.ITEM_ID             =ICA.ITEM_ID(+)
    AND IAV.ATTRIBUTE_ID          =ICA.ATTRIBUTE_ID(+)
    AND Iav.Loc_Attribute_Id      =La.Loc_Attribute_Id
    AND La.Locale_Id              =1
    AND Iav.Loc_Attribute_Uom_Id  =Lau.Loc_Attribute_Uom_Id(+)
    AND Iav.Loc_Attribute_Value_Id=Lav.Loc_Attribute_Value_Id
    GROUP BY Iav.Item_Id;
```

---

**Error:**

```
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.
```

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/357768?tstart=0 ... a concatenated string cannot exceed 4000 characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`COLLECT()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions024.htm) to aggregate the strings into a collection and then use a User-Defined function to concatenate the strings:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

CREATE FUNCTION concat_List(
  strings IN stringlist,
  delim   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN CLOB DETERMINISTIC
IS
  value CLOB;
  i     PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  IF strings IS NULL THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  value := EMPTY_CLOB();
  IF strings IS NOT EMPTY THEN
    i := strings.FIRST;
    LOOP
      IF i > strings.FIRST AND delim IS NOT NULL THEN
        value := value || delim;
      END IF;
      value := value || strings(i);
      EXIT WHEN i = strings.LAST;
      i := strings.NEXT(i);
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
  RETURN value;
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT Iav.Item_Id AS Attr_Item_Id,
       CONCAT_LIST(
         CAST(
           COLLECT(
             La.Attribute_Name || '|~|' || Lav.Attribute_Value ||' '|| Lau.Attribute_Uom
             ORDER BY ICA.DISP_SEQ,LA.ATTRIBUTE_NAME
           )
           AS stringlist
         ),
         '}~}'
       ) AS ATTR
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY iav.item_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

`LISTAGG` is limited to 4000 characters unfortunately. So you may want to use another approach to concatenate the values.

Anyway ...

It is strange to see `LISTAGG` which is a rather new feature combined with error-prone SQL1992 joins. I'd suggest you re-write this. Are the tables even properly joined? It looks strange that there seems to be no relation between `Loc_Attributes` and, say, `Loc_Attribute_Values`. Doesn't have `Loc_Attribute_Values` a `Loc_Attribute_Id` so an attribute value relates to an attribute? It would be hard to believe that there is no such relation.

Moreover: Is it guaranteed that your classification subquery doesn't return more than one record per attribute?

Here is your query re-written:

```
select 
  iav.item_id as attr_item_id,
  listagg(la.attribute_name || '|~|' || lav.attribute_value || ' ' || lau.attribute_uom,
   '}~}') within group (order by ica.disp_seq, la.attribute_name) as attr
from item_attribute_values iav
join loc_attribute_values lav 
       on lav.loc_attribute_value_id = iav.loc_attribute_value_id
       and lav.loc_attribute_id = iav.loc_attribute_id -- <== maybe?
join loc_attributes la 
       on la.loc_attribute_id = lav.loc_attribute_id 
       and la.loc_attribute_id = lav.loc_attribute_id -- <== maybe?
       and la.locale_id = 1
left join loc_attribute_uoms lau 
       on lau.loc_attribute_uom_id = iav.loc_attribute_uom_id
       and lau.loc_attribute_id = iav.loc_attribute_id -- <== maybe?
left join
(
  --  aggregation needed to get no more than one sortkey per item attribute?
  select ic.item_id, ca.attribute_id, min (ca.disp_seq) as disp_seq
  from item_classification ic
  join category_attributes ca on ca.taxonomy_tree_id = ic.taxonomy_tree_id
  where ic.default_category = 'y'
  group by ic.item_id, ca.attribute_id
) ica on ica.item_id = iav.item_id and ica.attribute_id = iav.attribute_id
group by iav.item_id;
```

Well, you get the idea; check your keys and alter your join criteria where necessary. Maybe this gets rid of duplicates, so `LISTAGG` has to concatenate less attributes, and maybe the result even stays within 4000 characters.

Comment: Removing duplicates is a sticking plaster on the problem at best; even without duplicates it is possible for the data set to grow and exceed the 4000 character limit (and who is to say that duplicates are not required) and then this answer (excluding the commentary on the legacy Oracle vs ANSI/ISO standard joins) can be reduced to "hope it doesn't happen" which is not an answer.

Comment: @MT0: I agree. And I actually wondered if I should write this as an "answer", but I didn't only want to say that the joins don't look proper (and this may cause all the trouble), but also demonstrate how to write them properly. This was just too much to but in a comment. It may well be that this is a small database with usually no more than, say, twenty attributes of thirty or so characters per item, so the limit of 4000 characters would not be an issue. But you are right; this is not really an answer, because it doesn't explain how to go about that limit. It may help, though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to write a small function to concatenate the strings into a CLOB, because even when you cast `TO_CLOB()` the `LISTAGG` at the end, this might not work.

Here´s a sample-function that takes a SELECT-Statement (which MUST return only one string-column!) and a separator and returns the collected values as a CLOB:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION listAggCLob(p_stringSelect VARCHAR2
                                      , p_separator VARCHAR2)
   RETURN CLOB
AS
   cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
   s VARCHAR2(4000);
   c CLOB;   
   i INTEGER; 
BEGIN
   dbms_lob.createtemporary(c, FALSE);
   IF (p_stringSelect IS NOT NULL) THEN
      OPEN cur FOR p_stringSelect;
      LOOP
         FETCH cur INTO s;
         EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
         dbms_lob.append(c, s || p_separator);
      END LOOP;
   END IF;
   i := length(c);
   IF (i > 0) THEN
      RETURN dbms_lob.substr(c,i-length(p_separator));
   ELSE
      RETURN NULL;
   END IF;
END;
```

This function can be used f.e. like this:

```
WITH cat AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT t1.category
     FROM lookup t1
   )
SELECT cat.category
     , listAggCLob('select t2.name from lookup t2 where t2.category = ''' || cat.category || '''', '|') allcategorynames  
  FROM cat;
```

Comment: This will append an extra delimiter to the end of the aggregated string.

Comment: Fixed: trailing Separator is clipped and also in case of nothing found, a NULL instead of empty CLOB is returned

Comment: When you remove the trailing separator you are removing a single character rather than removing a number of characters equal to the delimiter's length (which could be zero or greater than 1).

Comment: well, eagle-eyes ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Xquery approach. 
Creating extra types or function isn't necessary.

```
with test_tab
     as (select object_name
           from all_objects
          where rownum < 1000)
   , aggregate_to_xml as (select xmlagg(xmlelement(val, object_name)) xmls from test_tab)
select xmlcast(xmlquery('for $row at $idx in ./*/text() return  if($idx=1) then $row else concat(",",$row)'
                passing aggregate_to_xml.xmls returning content) as Clob) as list_in_lob
  from aggregate_to_xml;
```