# listagg throwing error - result of string concatenation is too long

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using below query to concatenate firware_version if we have same image_prerequisite for multiple firmware_version.
It is throwing me error

```
ORA - result of string concatenation is too long

SELECT device_count,
       dmc_id,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(image_prerequisite) OVER (PARTITION BY dmc_id, charging_group_id, image_prerequisite) > 1
       THEN listagg(firmware_version, '~') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY firmware_version) OVER (PARTITION BY dmc_id, charging_group_id, image_prerequisite)
        ELSE firmware_version
       END firmware_version,
       charging_group_id,
       image_prerequisite,
       count_within_dmcid
FROM   dm_temp_summing_dvc_by_fw
```

Please suggest some other way to achieve the same functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: LISTAGG has a 4000 character limit. Try looking at some of the previous times this question has been asked. Personally, I like the xmlagg solution, but there's a lot of options. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=listagg+4000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle : String Concatenation is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37829093/oracle-string-concatenation-is-too-long)